# Synchronized Google checkout AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, google-checkout

Is there a way to make it so when the order is processed I get a ajax request back to my site and don't have to refresh the page?  I know they have a call back url or a request url.  But I'm trying to make a module registration plug-in in which I can have the user go away from the module and pay and then get sent back to the module with the response they paid.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a callback to your server after the order is processed using the Notification API:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API.html

Regarding the redirect you want to implement, please keep in mind that an online purchase is not synchronous. There are security and credit checks that take place after the order is placed, and the order is accepted only after those checks pass.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I'll just have to input some type of programming for the module reappear when on the return.